# Ubuntu 20.04 battery life ASUS TUF FX505DT

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, power-management, battery

I'm a student and have a fresh dual boot of 20.04, and my concern is the battery life. It's almost at par with what the Windows 10 estimates suggest, but I wanted to know is there any way to improve it? I assumed ubuntu would be lighter than windows, but I'm getting the same if not less battery life as I used to get with Windows 10.

My configuration:

Ryzen 7 3750H with Vega 10 integrated graphics

NVidia GTX 1650 Mobile

Comment: "I assumed ubuntu would be lighter than windows" Nope. Ubuntu itself is on par with Windows. KDE uses a bit more. The off shoots like Budgie, lUbuntu, xUbuntu though are less resource prone.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your battery life by disabling few features that affect it. For example: lower your screen brightness and disable animations. Luckily there are some packages which help you achieve that such as **Slimbook Battery**, which you can install using apt:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:slimbook/slimbook

sudo apt update

sudo apt install slimbookbattery
```

Once you installed it, launch it from your **Show Applications** menu and you'll see a new icon appear on your ubuntu toolbar. You can choose from various battery modes but in your case you could use the "**Energy saving**" mode.